# adding unique key to many to many field in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have following models

```
class SettingAttributes(Core):
    attribute_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    setting_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SETTING_TYPES)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'core'
```

and

```
class SettingAttrValue(Core):
    attribute_value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    attribute_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(SettingAttributes)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    avaliases = models.TextField()
    attriblob = models.BinaryField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'core'
```

I want to add `unique_together` on  `SettingAttrValue` and `User`. If i do this in meta class of second model django is giving me error like `'unique_together' refers to a ManyToManyField 'user', but ManyToManyFields are not permitted in 'unique_together'.`

Answer (score 2):

Add `unique_together` to the [intermediate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) model:

```
class SettingAttrValue(Core):
    attribute_value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    attribute_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(SettingAttributes)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserSettingAttrValue')
    avaliases = models.TextField()
    attriblob = models.BinaryField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'core'


class UserSettingAttrValue(models.Model):
    setting_attr_value = models.ForeignKey(SettingAttrValue)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('setting_attr_value', 'user')
```

Comment: Yes, like I posted in my answer.

Comment: Database table will be created either way, adding class is just abstraction to apply unique constraint.

Comment: Technically `UserSettingAttrValue` isn't an object in the traditional sense, but it still feels weird to say that it knows which `SettingAttrValue` is using it, it really seems like `SettingAttrValue` should enforce uniqueness. The code here as written reads like "an entry knows which list it's in" whereas usually the list would manage object membership and an entry wouldn't know what list(s) it was a part of. I guess there's no better way other than to just abandon `ManyToManyField` and have `SettingAttrValue` have a `ForeignKey` into a different model.